# Java - Chinese characters are not displaying in generated (.rtf) document

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

In one of my Java Web application, the description field has to allow Chinese characters. In JSP form the field is allowing them properly as shown in picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/6w2K3.jpg , into the DataBase the data is inserting as TEST - &#27979;&#35797;&#35828;&#26126;
JSP is using UTF-8 encoding style, Database is MS SQL Server 2016 and the database column type is NTEXT.
There were no issues with JSP but, when generating reports (Like .rtf) this data is displaying in encoded string format i.e. TEST - &#27979;&#35797;&#35828;&#26126; not Chinese characters. 
Encoding type UTF-8 is using while generating report. 
Could any one help me in resolving this issue please.

Answer (score 0):

Those `&#27979;` and alike characters need to be decoded. Most likely, with JSP, you didn't need to decode them because the JSP was producing HTML and outputted this text as-is, which produces validly escaped HTML characters.

But RTF and others aren't HTML, so the same won't apply with them. For them you need to decode the characters before you try to output them.

Commons-lang's StringEscapeUtils will provide methods to do that. Or you could write your own decoder for it, it's almost trivially easy, in case you don't want to add a whole library just to do that.

Comment: In other words: `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml("... &#27979; ...")`

Comment: Hi Joop & kumesana, thank you so much for quick help,  Now the Chinese characters are displaying in my report.